# New menu and divider with angular 2 + material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I create this menu with material:

```
 <button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="topPosition color-md-icon">
  <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
 </button>
  <md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
 <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
    <span>1</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
    <span>2</span>
  </button>
  <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
    <span>3</span>
  </button>
</md-menu>
```

How to add some divider? `<md-divider>` not works. And how add new menu in my first item

```
 <button md-menu-item>
    <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
    <span>1</span>
  </button>
```

How implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For now, `<md-divider>` is part of `MdListModule`, if you import it into your module definition you will be able to use `<md-divider>` between your `md-menu-item``s. Like so:

```
<button md-menu-item>
  <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
  <span>1</span>
</button>
<md-divider></md-divider>
<button md-menu-item>
  <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
  <span>2</span>
</button>
```

P.S. there is an [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/5524) about moving `<md-divider>` out of `MdListModule`.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking into this and it appears that  is not included as part of material.angular.io.  You can see the feature list here: https://github.com/angular/material2.

I guess you'll have to go with `<hr>` instead. :/

Answer (score 1):

As a quick hack, add an empty md-list somewhere in the page where you want to use md-divider:

```
<md-list></md-list>
```

This will cause list.css to load, and allow you to use md-divider in md-menu, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button md-icon-button [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu" class="topPosition color-md-icon">
    <md-icon>more_vert</md-icon>
</button>
<md-menu #menu="mdMenu">
    <button md-menu-item [mdMenuTriggerFor]="menu2" class="topPosition color-md-icon">
        <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
        <span>1</span>
    </button>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <md-menu #menu2="mdMenu">
        <button md-menu-item>
            <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
            <span>1</span>
        </button>
        <button md-menu-item>
            <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
            <span>2</span>
        </button>
        <button md-menu-item>
            <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
            <span>3</span>
        </button>
    </md-menu>
    <button md-menu-item>
        <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
        <span>2</span>
    </button>
    <button md-menu-item>
        <md-icon>cloud</md-icon>
        <span>3</span>
    </button>
</md-menu>
```

Comment: i would like this: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/menuBar, see: File -> New and after i click open new menu. And divider is not works.

Comment: do you know hot to implement what i write up?